# SQL Group By + Aggregate functions with joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables:
1. EMPLOYEE_DATA and its columns as

```
EMP_ID  MANAGER_ID
9999      2222
8888      2222
7777      2222
```

Another table is :
2. EMPLOYEE_RECORDS:

```
EMP_ID MANAGER_ID NO_OF_SWIPEINS ATTENDACE_DATE
9999   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
7777   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
9999   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
9999   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
```

I want the data in below format:

```
EMP_ID        MANAGER_ID       TODAY_SWIPEINS
9999            2222                 3
8888            2222                 0
7777            2222                 1
```

I tried below query:

```
    SELECT edata.EMP_ID, sum(rec.NO_OF_SWIPEINS) as TODAY_SWIPEINS,edata.MANAGER_ID FROM EMPLOYEE_RECORDS  rec 
right JOIN EMPLOYEE_DATA  edata
ON edata.MANAGER_ID = rec.MANAGER_ID 
and rec.MANAGER_ID='2222' and trunc(rec.ATTENDANCE_DATE)='23-DEC-2017'
group by edata.EMP_ID ,edata.MANAGER_ID;
```

But getting below results:

```
EMP_ID    TODAY_SWIPEINS      MANAGER_ID
8888           4                2222
7777           4                2222
9999           4                2222
```

Someone please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: But I dont have those records in table 2 which I have in table 1

Comment: You can't have 8888 as it is not present in EMPLOYEE_RECORDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should select data from `employee_data` and then join with table 2.

check this:

```
SELECT ED.MANAGER_ID, ED.EMP_ID, COUNT(NO_OF_SWIPEINS), IFNULL(ATTENDACE_DATE, '23-DEC-2017') as ATTENDACE_DATE  FROM EMPLOYEE_DATA ED
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_RECORDS ER
ON ER.EMP_ID = ED.EMP_ID AND ATTENDACE_DATE = '23-DEC-2017'
WHERE ED.MANAGER_ID = 222 
GROUP BY ED.MANAGER_ID, ED.EMP_ID;
```

`here is`:[slqfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ea759/13)

Comment: Your query is somehow good but why are you not filtering out the '23-DEC-2017' data? To me your answer seems correct because all the data are having the same `ATTENDANCE_DATE` else your answer will be falsy.

Comment: @cdaiga you are right. my source table is `employee_data`. updated my answer.

Comment: Good but the query can be better; the attendance_date can be set to the current date so that one won't have to repeat the changing the date every day one runs the query. Check my answer below, but yours is correct so I will vote it :) . Happy feast!

Comment: Also `'23-DEC-2017'` isn't a date. A date would be something like `date '2017-12-23'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select EMP_ID,MANAGER_ID sum(NO_OF_SWIPEINS) as TODAY_SWIPEINS from EMPLOYEE_RECORDS group by EMP_ID;
```

> You don't need to join two tables as the EMPLOYEE_RECORDS contains
>   all data to manipulate. Now as you have no provision for Emp_ID 8888
>   so the final query would show nothing for 8888. For that you need
>   include. So your EMPLOYEE_RECORDS table must look like this in order
>   to get exact output as you mentioned.

```
EMP_ID MANAGER_ID NO_OF_SWIPEINS ATTENDACE_DATE
9999   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
7777   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
9999   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
9999   2222         1             23-DEC-2017
8888   2222         0             23-DEC-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

You were joining only on `MANAGER_ID` and not on `EMP_ID`. Check the below improved query.

```
SELECT edata.EMP_ID, edata.MANAGER_ID, sum(rec.NO_OF_SWIPEINS) as TODAY_SWIPEINS 
FROM 
EMPLOYEE_RECORDS rec right JOIN EMPLOYEE_DATA  edata
ON edata.MANAGER_ID = rec.MANAGER_ID and edata.EMP_ID = rec.EMP_ID
and rec.MANAGER_ID='2222' and trunc(rec.ATTENDANCE_DATE)='23-DEC-2017'
group by edata.EMP_ID ,edata.MANAGER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that does what you wanted, the `ATTENDANCE_DATE` is set to the current date.

```
SELECT B.EMP_ID, B.MANAGER_ID, COUNT(A.NO_OF_SWIPEINS) TODAY_SWIPEINS FROM 
(SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_RECORDS WHERE ATTENDACE_DATE=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%b-%Y')) A
RIGHT JOIN EMPLOYEE_DATA B
ON A.EMP_ID=B.EMP_ID
GROUP BY B.EMP_ID, B.MANAGER_ID;
```

Here is an SQL Fiddle [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b71b3/14) of the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but why were you joining by manager_id?. `NULL` handling was required while calculating `SUM`. Also, it is preferable to use `TO_DATE` while doing comparison with a date column, `attendance_date`

```
SELECT edata.emp_id,
       edata.manager_id,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN rec.no_of_swipeins IS NULL THEN 0
             ELSE rec.no_of_swipeins
           END) AS TODAY_SWIPEINS
FROM   employee_records rec
       RIGHT JOIN employee_data edata
               ON edata.emp_id = rec.emp_id
                  AND rec.manager_id = '2222'
                  AND TRUNC(rec.attendance_date) =
                      To_date('23-DEC-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'
                      )
GROUP  BY edata.emp_id,
          edata.manager_id;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa1ebc/21)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT edata.EMP_ID, nvl(sum(rec.NO_OF_SWIPEINS), 0) as TODAY_SWIPEINS,edata.MGR_ID 
FROM EMPONE  edata left JOIN MGRONE  rec
ON edata.EMP_ID = rec.EMP_ID 
group by edata.EMP_ID ,edata.MGR_ID
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.